# Why can't create resource for DRBD on CentOS 7?

Tags: linux, centos, drbd

Follow this guide to install DRBD on CentOS 7.3:

http://www.learnitguide.net/2016/07/how-to-install-and-configure-drbd-on-linux.html

After this step:

```
resource testdata1 {
protocol C;           
on node1 {
        device /dev/drbd0;
        disk /dev/sdb;
        address 172.16.2.61:7788;
        meta-disk internal;
    }
    on node2 {
        device /dev/drbd0;
        disk /dev/sdb;
        address 172.16.2.62:7788;
        meta-disk internal;
    }
}
```

When run :

```
drbdadm create-md testdata1
```

Got message:

```
'testdata1' not defined in your config (for this host).
```

The `/etc/hosts` is:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

172.16.2.61              node1.clusterbr.int   node1
172.16.2.62              node2.clusterbr.int   node2
172.16.2.60              dbip.clusterbr.int   node1
```

The `/etc/drbd.conf` config is:

```
# You can find an example in  /usr/share/doc/drbd.../drbd.conf.example

include "drbd.d/global_common.conf";
include "drbd.d/*.res";
```

What's the reason of the problem?

Comment: Are these config files are both hosts?

Comment: @RamanSailopal Do you mean the content in the `/etc/hosts`? Yes.

Comment: No I mean the drbd files?

Comment: @RamanSailopal Yes, I added the `/etc/drbd.conf` to the question. Both hosts has that config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was didn't set the right hostname on drbd config file.

Use `uname -a` can see the hostname. Set it to config.

Thanks to this:

https://newbiedba.wordpress.com/2015/09/21/drbd-not-defined-in-your-config-for-this-host/

Answer (score 1):

To Solve this issue
Note: Same configuration file present on both host under `/etc/drbd.d/*.res`

1. First allow communication on port `7788`
2. Then check hostname of nodes `# hostname` and verify `#vi /etc/sysconfig/network` contain same hostname
3. Last but not least

   `# vi /etc/hosts`

   `<IP1> node1.abc.com node1`

   `<IP2> node2.abc.com node2`

   ... save it and then
4. `#drbdadm create-md testdata1`

Best Luck

Answer (score 0):

in the tutorial when editing "etc/drbd.d/testdata1.res"
on node1
on node2

those two are the name of the machine.
you need to replace those by yours.
example : 
on machine1
on machine2

Answer (score 0):

```
resource testdata1 {
protocol C;           
on node1 {  <<<<<<<<<<<< put your host name by useing CMD "hostname" istead of node1

        device /dev/drbd0;
        disk /dev/sdb;
        address 172.16.2.61:7788;
        meta-disk internal;
    }
    on node2 { <<<<<<< put your host name by useing CMD "hostname" istead of node2

        device /dev/drbd0;
        disk /dev/sdb;
        address 172.16.2.62:7788;
        meta-disk internal;
    }
}
```